# How to create dynamic Dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1267

Im not certain how to link the code,
Hello Everyone, I am new to HTML and Javascript. I am trying to create dynamic dropdown menus as seen in the website provided. I downloaded the source code and it works perfectly but my main question is how could I get the drop down options from an XML page rather that hard coding it. I want to create something that is like Country - State- Town, so If i choose USA it would go options that are only available for the USA and so forth. In the code above it splits the string so the value is first and the label is second. Is it possible someone can help me, I am trying to help my older brother. What would be a certain way to complete this, using AJAX if so is it possible I can only use Javascript like the code above? thank you

Comment: jsFiddle for the code posted by OP: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/BS7Lp/

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to use AJAX for fetching data, however you will have to change the code a bit. You can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/BS7Lp/3/

```
//Assuming this is the object returned via AJAX
var ajaxResult = {
    Chevy: ["|", "camaro|Camaro", "corvette|Corvette", "impala|Impala"],
    Dodge: ["|", "avenger|Avenger", "challenger|Challenger", "charger|Charger"],
    Ford: ["|", "mustang|Mustang", "shelby|Shelby"],
    SomeMore: ["|", "more|More", "options|Options"]
};

function init() {
    document.getElementById("slct1").options.add(
        document.createElement("option")
    );
    for (var names in ajaxResult) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = names;
        option.innerHTML = names;
        document.getElementById("slct1").options.add(option);
    }
}

function populate(s1, s2) {
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
    s2.innerHTML = "";
    var optionArray = ajaxResult[s1.value];
    for (var option in optionArray) {
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        s2.options.add(newOption);
    }
}

init();  //Call this when you have the object from AJAX
```

Comment: This seems good but it is possible to get the information from an XML page? I am trying to make a form that people can update the drop downs without looking at the code, I was wondering if it is possible to create a form that updates a XML page and then the XML page updates the dropdown menu like Country - state- city, because I am trying to create the country state city exaple so 3 tiered, thanks in advanced

Comment: @user3773023 - You can obtain the data from an XML page with `XMLHttpRequest`. Then you can loop through the nodes similar to the code I have here and appending the options into the form. I used JSON here since it is easier to work with.

Comment: I do apologize for all these questions, its just that I want to learn a lot, but where would I specify the XMLHttpRequest, and how could I edit the XML from a form, is it possible you can provide another example of code? I am still not understanding how to do it but I understand the conceptual portion. Also is Ajax the only way to complete the country-state-city drop down via XML? or is there an easier way, thanks in advanced

Comment: Creating a form to modify XMLs on the server is a completely different topic. It involves some server-side stuff to deal with. About your second question, [AJAX is just a name for "fetching data from the server and using it"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX), so AJAX is the only way to do it. The two most popular data types are JSON and XML, and the easiest type to deal with is [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/JSON).

Comment: So on the topic of getting the input from XML via XMLHttpRequest, all I would have to do is use this to get the data from the XML, and then use the code you have provided above? thanks in advanced

Comment: @user3773023 - Basically yes, with some modifications to the code depending how the XML is structured.

Comment: in ajaxResult = [... ] would I have to replace it with XMLHTTPrequest from the XML? so instead of hard coding it i would reference the XML instead of the ajaxResult

Comment: Take a look at [how XMLHttpRequest works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). When the XML file is received, transform it into an object and assign it to `ajaxResult`.